# Why doesn't this dojo.mvc.Repeat work in a templated widget?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'd like to create a templated Dojo widget with a repeated element to it.  From reading the documentation on dojotoolkit.org, it seems like this should work:

widget.js:

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/_WidgetBase',
    'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
    'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
    'dojo/text!./test.html',
    'dojox/mvc/getStateful',
    'dojox/mvc/Repeat',
    'dojox/mvc/Output',
    'dojox/mvc/at',
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
            template, getStateful) {
    var data = getStateful([
        {
            'id': 1
        },
        {
            'id': 2
        }
    ]);

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: template,
        data: data
    });
});
```

test.html:

```
<section>
    <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
    <div data-dojo-type='dojox.mvc.Output' data-dojo-props="value: at(this.data[0], 'id')"></div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Repeat" data-dojo-props="children: this.data">
        <div>REPEAT</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

However, the Output widget appears to correctly retrieve the first id, but the Repeat doesn't display anything.

Why is Repeat not working here?  I saw some posts saying that WidgetList is potentially replacing Repeat, but it has the same behavior (i.e., does not display anything).  Am I missing something, or is this the intended behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it didn’t work for you, but I tried to put the following HTML to the same directory as your widget.js and test.html, and it worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: 0, async: 1"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require({
                paths: {
                    "widgetlistintemplate": location.pathname
                }
            }, ["dojo/parser"], function (parser) {
                parser.parse();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-dojo-type="widgetlistintemplate/widget"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

BTW, you are right that dojox/mvc/WidgetList is the successor dojox/mvc/Repeat. dojox/mvc/Repeat has been deprecated.

Hope this helps.

Best, - Akira

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It looks like my problem may be trying to insert it programmatically; your example works fine for me, but if I try to insert the widget manually it no longer works:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["widgetlistintemplate/widget", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(Widget) {
            var widget = new Widget();
            widget.placeAt(dojo.body(), "first");
        });
</script>`

Is there something I'm missing for programmatically inserting a widget?  Sorry, I'm new to dojo so maybe it's something glaringly obvious.

Comment: I guess what you needed is running `widget.startup()`? Many Dojo widgets requires that call for proper initialisation.

Comment: Perfect, that was it exactly.  Thanks!